# Firebase authentication expiration duration

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

When I use `generateEmailVerificationLink` , I want to notice the link expiration date to user.

But I couldn't find the document...

Comment: It's not documented afaik but its roughly 2-3 days

Answer (score 3):

After quite some research I've managed to find out the following:

```
Password reset (generatePasswordResetLink): 1 hour
Email verification (generateEmailVerificationLink): 3 days
Email link sign-in (generateSignInWithEmailLink): 6 hours
```

This is still not in the official Firebase documentation and may a subject to change in the future.

Here is the source I found: [Firebase Admin Auth Link Expiration Times](https://medium.com/@beard0/firebase-admin-auth-link-expiration-times-9b5b090eae37)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Actually, I know the site. But I doubted whether the information was genuine...

The site seems to be reliable, so I will develop it with the information you gave me.

Comment: I generated bunch of links and tested signin in every hour, stopped working after 6 hours, so the sign in link generated with admin.auth().generateSignInWithEmailLink expires after 6 hours.
{ message: "EXPIRED_OOB_CODE", domain: "global", reason: "invalid" }